# Retaining the Phongness even after material change in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, onkeydown

I tried loading my `.obj` and `.mtl` files and now I'm trying to change the material of the object on keypress, I'm able to do changes as expected using texture images. However when I want to change materials using a phong effect with or without texture image it's not happening.

//THIS METHOD IS WORKING FINE WHEN I USE BASIC TEXTURE IMAGES ON KEYPRESS

```
var texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("neavik/9.jpg");
var texture2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("neavik/10.jpg");

if (child.material.name == "meta") {
child.material.map = texture1;
child.material.needsUpdate = true;
child.receiveShadow = true;


var index = 0;
var onKeyDown = function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 67) { // when 'c' is pressed
        object.traverse(function(child) {
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    var colors = [texture2, texture1];
                    if (child.material.name == "meta") {

                        if (index == colors.length) index = 0;
                        child.material.map = colors[index++];
                        child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                        child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                        child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyDown, true);

    });
```

// Now if i try to change materials with same effect like PHONG it doesn't reflect any changes on Keypress.[ No errors as well ]

```
var texture1 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("neavik/9.jpg");
var texture2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("neavik/10.jpg");

var cleana = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: texture1,
    color: 0xffffef,
    specular: 0x000000,
    combine: THREE.AddOperation,
    reflectivity: 0
})

var cleanb = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    map: texture2,
    color: 0xffffef,
    specular: 0x000000,
    combine: THREE.AddOperation,
    reflectivity: 0
})

if (child.material.name == "meta") {

    child.material = cleana;
    child.material.needsUpdate = true;

    child.receiveShadow = true;


    var index = 0;

    var onKeyDown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 67) { // when 'c' is pressed

            object.traverse(function(child) {
                    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                        var colors = [cleana, cleanb];
                        if (child.material.name == "meta") {

                            if (index == colors.length) index = 0;
                            child.material = colors[index++];
                            child.material.needsUpdate = true;
                            child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
                            child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;

                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            document.addEventListener('keyup', onKeyDown, true);

        });
```

Please let me know if there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exchange the whole material you need to do:

```
child.material = cleana;
```

or

```
child.material = cleanb;
```

and then you most likely have to do:

```
child.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Read more on how to update material [in this **How to update things** reference page in the chapter **Materials**](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates#materials)

### UPDATE

So if you want to set using an array:

```
var materials = [cleana, cleanb];

child.material = materials[0]; // cleana
```

or

```
child.material = materials[1]; // cleanb
```

and then also most likely:

```
child.material.needsUpdate = true;
```

---

It works totally fine with an array of materials. You don't even need to set `material.needsUpdate = true`. A demonstration [here in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/tsv7vLta/).

Comment: this exactly works as you said, i have tried it. But when i use the same cleana and cleanb in a array, it dosent reflect any changes on keypress.

Comment: @andyram I updated my answer. I would not see any reason why it would not work from an array.

Comment: Thanks for the update, i have tried this method before, for me this  material[0] works only when there is no material applied to the object. Changes do not reflect when i call this array to an object with an already existing material and i wanted to loop few materials on keypress.

Comment: @andyram It works fine. [Here a fiddle with a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/tsv7vLta/)

Comment: @andyram Did you check out my update with the fiddle?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, i tried using  the same method like in the fiddle, but the result is same, for some reason its not working

Comment: @andyram Then provide a fiddle where you demonstrate that it isn't working for your specific case. Right now I am unable to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115823/discussion-between-andy-ram-and-wilt).

Comment: i have made a sample of my method please have a look here
http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andyram08/neavik/master/issue.html

Github repo 
https://github.com/andyram08/neavik/blob/master/issue.html
please have a look.

Comment: @@wilt did you look at this updated code ? Please let me know what you think.